# get another sequence elements'value in one sequence

Tags: xslt

I have an XML file as below, and I want to transform it with xslt.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <s1 name="kfb" />
    <s1 name="kfb" />
    <s1 name="kfb" />
    <s1 name="kfb" />
    <s1 name="kfb" />
    <s1 name="kfb" />
    <summary>
        <r1  value="1" />
        <r1  value="5" />
        <r1  value="c" />
        <r1  value="h" />
        <r1  value="3" />
        <r1  value="1" />
    </summary>
</root>
```

what I want to achieve is: when do the for-each of "s1" elements, I want to get the corresponding "r1"'s "value" attbute value just according the index/postion("s1" elements count equal "r1") . the xslt I wrote as below, but it does not work, can anyone give a help? thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template mode="getr1" match="summary" >
        <xsl:param name="index"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="r1[$index][@value]"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <ul>
                <xsl:for-each select="root/s1">
                    <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()"/>
                    <li>
                        <xsl:value-of select ="@name"/>
                        :
                        <!--<xsl:apply-templates mode="getr1" select="/root/summary">
                            <xsl:with-param name="index" select="$i" />
                        </xsl:apply-templates>-->
                        <!--I want to get the corresponding r1's value according to the index -->
                        <!-- but above code is not work.-->
                    </li>
                </xsl:for-each>
                </ul>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: If anything, it would be `r1[$index]/@value`, not `r1[$index][@value]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="root">
  <html>
    <body>
      <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="s1" />
      </ul>
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="s1">
  <!-- remember current position -->
  <xsl:variable name="myPos" select="position()" />
  <li>
    <xsl:text>Name: </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>

    <xsl:text>Value: </xsl:text>
    <!-- use current position to pull out the correct <r1> -->
    <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::summary[1]/r1[$myPos]/@value"/>

    <!-- if there is only ever one <summary> in your XML, you can also do -->
    <xsl:value-of select="/root/summary/r1[$myPos]/@value"/>
  </li>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with the `getr1` template

you access the value attribute with `<xsl:value-of select="r1[$index][@value]"/>` but is should be `<xsl:value-of select="r1[$index]/@value"/>`